# How can I plot this time series in a single graph on python importing from excel?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib

I am trying to have a single graph displaying a 10 series. These are divided in group such as this simple example (Under each groupA/B should be S1-5, S6-10) example:

|  | Group A | Group B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| time(h) | S1 | S2 | S4 | S6 |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 5 |
| 24 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 48 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 |

How can I add these 6 series in a single graph and categorise their group A/B by colour ?

So far I am importing from excel sheet1 as this:

f = r"C:\Path.xlsm"
df = pd.read_excel(f)

But I do not know how to get it by CLASS A and B and colour them differently.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does my answer provide the solution you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I guess groupby is what you're searching for...
how about something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1,2,3,4,5], B=[1,1.5,2,3.5,5]))

f, ax = plt.subplots()

for key, val in df.groupby(axis=1, level=0):
    ax.plot(val, label=key)
ax.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my Excel table:

|  | Group A |  |  | Group B |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| time(h) | S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 | S5 | S6 |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 24 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 |
| 48 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 |

When importing the Excel table, you should indicate that the column headers are hierarchical with `header=[0, 1]` and that the leftmost column contains the index `index_col=0`, like this:

```
import pandas as pd              # v 1.1.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # v 3.3.2

# Import Excel spreadsheet data into a pandas DataFrame
file_path = 'C:\path\\groups_time_series.xlsx'
df_groups = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=[0, 1], index_col=0)
```

```
df_groups

#           Group A     Group B
#  time(h)  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
#        0   1   3   2   3   4   5
#       24   2   1   3   4   5   1
#       48   3   2   2   1   3   2
```

You can then plot each group in one go on the same plot (`ax=ax`) by looping over level 0 of the columns `MultiIndex`, like in the following example:

```
# Create figure with single Axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,4))

# Select colors for each group and plot each group by selecting the
# cross-sections of the DataFrame at the group level
colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange']
for group, color in zip(df_groups.columns.levels[0], colors):
    df_groups.plot(y=group, color=color, ax=ax)

# Additional formatting
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_xlabel('Time (h)', labelpad=10)
ax.set_ylabel('Value (unit)', labelpad=10)
ax.legend(frameon=False, loc=(1.05, 0.3))
ax.set_title('Line chart of Group A (blue) and Group B (orange)', pad=30, fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

[image: groups_time_series]